# ui-router - Default substate based on data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a list of modules with module detail on the right side.

```
div
  ul
    li(data-ng-repeat="module in modules")
      a(ng-href="{{getModuleHref(module)}}")
  div(ui-view)
```

Both module list and each module has it's own state. I want the parent state to be addressable, therefore no abstract.

```
.state('modules', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: ..
})
.state('modules.input', {
  url: '/input',
  templateUrl: ..
})
...
```

When accessing the list without explicitly selected module, I want to have selected first failed module. (redirect to another state based on downloaded data)

I've tried several paths without success:

a) `state.onEnter` - is not triggered when redirecting from child state (e.g. the back button or manual url change) and `$state.current` is not target state yet (so I do not know if we aren't in the child state already)

b) redirect in `$urlRouterProvider` - absence of downloaded data and I'm unable to download it (sync vs async)

c) global `$stateChangeSuccess` handling .. unability to access the data (even if it should be already downloaded via state.resolve) - so this one is probably managable at the cost of getting data multiple times.

So I've been left with changing state in controller's constructor and registering custom  `$stateChangeSuccess` inside a controller to handle the back button/manual url edit.

```
function ModulesController($scope, apiService, $state, $rootScope) {
  var _this = this;
  this.scope = $scope;

  this.getInitialJobTraceDetail = function () {
    apiService.getModules(function (modules) {
      _this.scope.modules = modules;
      _this.setDefaultState();
    });
  };

  this.setDefaultState = function () {
    if (_this.$state.current.name != 'modules')
      return;
    var targetModule = _this.getFailedModule();
    _this.$state.go(targetModule);
  };

  this.setupModulesStateWatch = function () {
    _this.registerOnStateChangeEvent();
    _this.scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
      _this.unregisterOnStateChangeEvent();
    });
  };

  this.registerOnStateChangeEvent = function () {
    _this.unregisterOnStateChangeEvent = _this.$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState) {
    if (toState.name == 'modules') {
      _this.setDefaultState();
    }
  });

  this.getInitialJobTraceDetail();
  this.setupJobDetailStateWatch();
}
```

Edit: But I think there should be a better solution. Working with state inside a controller doesn't feel right - my other state-hadling code is in global separate file. Maybe that is the problem and state-handling/definitions should be with corresponding components?

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify why do I think my solution is not ideal. But based on your answer - maybe the question should really be: In the ui-router sample, there is always controller inside of state definition. If we have bigger application and do want to separe controller to it's own file - should state definition follow him?

Comment: Just a hint: In this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/OFoMJckH4283law0wqgE?p=preview you can see the power of the https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve **resolve** feature setting. The state itself, before is invoked does some investigation. Controller just recieves the right param. It can call $state.go() with that param, if param is not null.

Comment: I've met resolve during my research (see a note in third try). It looks great but since the page should have auto-refresh too (example is simplified), I didn't like the idea of implementing two ways how to get data in the controller (direct data inject and api service for refresh)

Comment: These were just hints... not an answer ;)